# css center floating divs horizontally

Tags: html, css

I want my page to center floating divs regardless of page width and number of divs per row.

if page fits three divs per row, and I have four divs, I want fourth div to be under first div. if user makes window wider, then fourth div moves up to first row:

```
[ [div1]  [div2]  [div3]  [div4] ]


[ [div1]  [div2]  [div3] ]
[ [div4]                 ]


[  [div1]  [div2]  ]
[  [div3]  [div4]  ]
```

I tried making container div text-align:center and content divs inline-block but that makes divs in last row centered like this:

```
[ [div1]  [div2]  [div3] ]
[         [div4]         ]
```

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/g8L1ovj0/

Comment: Have you got example code of what you've already tried?

Comment: Your floating divs have fixed width? Just remove text-align: center from your container div, and floating divs will be arranged as you want. Also, you can use clearfix for your concainer and float: left for your divs, or use flexbox

Comment: @Aaron I added jsfiddle example.

Comment: @dajnz If I remove text-aligne: center the divs wont be centered on the page but all will be aligned left.

Answer (score 2):

`flexbox` can do that

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 25px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #000;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/XbBaJe)

Comment: Thank you, this flexbox is new to me. It looks browser support is also only recent. Is this css3 standard or something separate? I will test some more to see if it breaks something else.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but has an issue. If you have 3 divs in the first row and 2 divs in the second row,  the second div of second row will align to the rightmost, rather than under the second div of the first row. Try to re-size the browser so that you have more than 2 boxes in the upper rows and 2 boxes (or less boxes) in lowest row. http://jsfiddle.net/abdfahim/yyr1w5kq/2/